# Python Selenium - How to remove whitespacing/spaces from outtputted text?

Tags: python, selenium, spaces, removing-whitespace

Hey guys I for sure reason cannot figure out how to remove whitespaces/spaces from printed out text. I am using an audio to text bot, for captcha and it outputs the text fine except for sometimes the bot creates random spaces if it doesnt recognise what the word is saying.

An example would be it guessed the word right but this happens:

- FE R2B
- C39 3OP
- 95 4JGE
- YU J51 A

I am sure you know what I mean by this, if not ^ it just randomly creates spaces when it outputs the audio to text. I have tried the .strip() functions but they dont seem to work or maybe I am just doing it wrong, yes I have checked many forums to see if I could get it working but I just cannot figure it out hence why I am asking here.

Here is the code so you can understand it more:

```
key=r.recognize_google(audio)
    print("[INFO] Recaptcha Passcode: %s"%key)
    time.sleep(3)
    CaptchaKey = driver.find_element_by_id("captcha-value").send_keys(key)
    time.sleep(4)
    Submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/main/div[3]/div/div[2]/form/div/fieldset[15]/div/input').click()

    if driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="reg-captcha"]/span').is_displayed():
        print('CaptchaFailed')
```

The print out part is where it shows what the captcha would look like and then sends what it would look like into the text box but again it comes with spaces the audio bot created trying to figure out what the word was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to remove white space from the outputted text string...

```
text = 'FE R2B'
text = text.replace(' ', '')
print(text)

FER2B
```

**Updated Code** For your specific scenario:

```
key=r.recognize_google(audio)
key = key.replace(' ', '')
print("[INFO] Recaptcha Passcode: %s"%key)
```

Comment: I dont need it in that expression type. The text is dynamic and changes when the bot changes the audio to text...

Comment: Ok, can't you just grab whatever the value is and use the same replace() method shown above? It doesn't matter if it's dynamic or not.

Comment: How would i go about implementing that in if it doesnt matter? because I am calling to the key from the google audio

Comment: Your question was `how to remove whitespacing/spaces from outputted text` and that is what I gave you in my answer.  I assumed you had a `text` value you can work with. I don't see what audio has to do with this.  Audio just creates the text, correct? And the text returned sometimes has spaces in it? Whatever that value is you can use the `replace()` method shown above to then strip the whitespaces from it and then move onto whatever the next task is.  If I am misunderstanding your need then disregard my answer

Comment: I just updated my answer with some code specific to your scenario, if I am understanding you correctly.